# How do I create two pages so that one page displays what is inputted into the other?

Tags: php, mysql, html

(I'm a beginner)

As a simple exercise, I want to create two web pages, so that text inputted in one page is displayed on the other. I really am not sure how to go about it, and I want guidance.
I think I need to use some combination of HTML/PHP/MySQL, but I'm not sure.

I have MAMP and Aptana installed. I have previously set up a server using MAMP and was able to send and retrieve data from it.

Do I set up a table on my server, and use PHP to post and retrieve data from it? Or some other way?

Comment: this is not rent a programmer for free website!

Comment: Please be more specific. Your other question mentioned User/Password saving, are you looking to create a user login? In which case, I suggest looking into creating a secure login script with PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is overly broad.

You should read on some tutorial / doc and learn how to develop web site first.

There are [tons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Web_Development) and [tons](http://www.w3schools.com/) and [tons](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql) of resources on the web.

For a sample on form submission, look [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php).

Good luck :)